# Unable to get response for raw request in php

Tags: php, api, request

Hi for this great community. I'm new ones to create api's in php. The problem is I'm not able to get the response when i send the raw request from the postman.Here is my code for raw_request_api.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['json'])) {
    $jsonobj = $_REQUEST['json'];
    $json = json_decode($jsonobj);
    echo json_encode($json);
}else
    echo "Unable to get the request data";

?>
```

I'm getting the response when I use Form data as well as x-www-form-urlencoded.
[image: form-data]

[image: x-www-form-urlencoded.]

But I'm not able to get the response from the raw data.
[image]
Please help me where i'm making the mistake? Also I tried every format for raw data...like text/html, application/json, application/xml, text/xml...nothing works

Comment: I tried header('Content-type: application/json');
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json_decode = json_decode($json, true); 
$json_encode = json_encode($json_decode);
echo $json_encode; but the isset($_REQUEST['json']) is returning false and executing else statement